# Send message to dynamic kafka topic in helidon

Tags: apache-kafka, helidon

In Quarkus/small rye, we can send message to dynamic topic. Please check the below link for the example.

https://beyondvelocity.blog/2022/01/05/dynamic-kafka-topics-in-quarkus/

Kindly suggest how can we implement same in Helidon

I could not find equivalent api or classes in helidon to send message to dynamic topic.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing preventing you from using `KafkaProducer` + `ProducerRecord` classes directly and calling send method with any topic String parameter

Otherwise, just create the Channel with the topic name when you need a dynamic value

```java
KafkaConnector kafkaConnector = KafkaConnector.create();

messaging = Messaging.builder()
        .publisher(
             Channel.<String>builder()
                .subscriberConfig(KafkaConnector.configBuilder()
                .bootstrapServers(kafkaServer)
                .topic("some random string")
                .keySerializer(StringSerializer.class)
                .valueSerializer(StringSerializer.class)
                .build()
             ).build(), 
             Multi.just("test1", "test2").map(Message::of)  // example messages
        )
        .connector(kafkaConnector)
        .build()
        .start();
```

https://helidon.io/docs/v2/#/se/reactivemessaging/04_kafka